# Using getBytes to setAttachment in Junit

Tags: java, junit

Below is the code that i have used for junit to save an attachment. It got saved in DB but when i browse through an application got an error message like " could not open 'test109.pdf' because it is either not supported file type or the may be damaged". It is the same for other file types too. is there any problem in using **.getBytes** here?

```
@Test 
public void saveAttachment() throws SerException
{

final File blobIn = new File("F:\\src\\test4.pdf");
    InputStream blobIs = null;
    try {
        blobIs = new FileInputStream(blobIn);   
AttachmentReqDocument attachmentReqDocument = AttachmentReqDocument.Factory.newInstance();
    AttachmentReq attachmentReq = attachmentReqDocument.addNewSaveAttachmentReq();
    attachmentReq.setSuId("105"); 
    attachmentReq.setTId("104532520"); 
    attachmentReq.setFileName("test109.pdf"); 
    attachmentReq.setAttachment("test112".getBytes()); 
    attachmentReq.setUserId("test004"); 
    attachmentReqDocument.getSaveAttachmentReq().setInUserId(null);
    AttachmentResDocument attachmentResDocument =       
            testManager.saveTestAttachment(attachmentReqDocument);
    System.out.println(attachmentResDocument);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Error Reading the bytes");
    }
}
```

Any of your help is really appreciated :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Err yes, "test112" doesn't constitute a valid PDF document. Isn't that expected? What's the use of `blobIn` and `blobIs` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to attach the bytes from the `blobIs` inputStream instead of `"test112".getBytes()` which is obviously not valid pdf encoded data.